# Windows 10 through university, graduated and lost access to login, no admin account

Tags: windows, user-accounts

I downloaded windows through my university to a personal PC. I think it was windows 10 education.

After graduation they removed access to my connected accounts and I didn't realize that the PC login account goes through the school still. I never set up a different account on the computer (like a dummy). When signing in it says "can't sign in with this account." When trying to reset the password/pin it says, tell organization's IT that can't access some URL with the school's domain.

Called school IT and they just suggeseted I download a different windows liscence and download a fresh windows 10.

I tried shift+restart > troubleshooting > command prompt
shift+restart > reset this PC (keep files)
But those required signing in and there was no admin account to sign into.

Most of my stuff is online but there are a few files that hadn't been backed up in a while that I would want. Is there any way for me to get back into my files?

Comment: You need to ask your school IT if they will find a way to get your files and give them to you. You cannot natively take ownership of  your files without an Admin ID

Comment: I think the key here is that user wants to get access to their files. As @harrymc pointed out a  Linux Live USB and other approaches would work if  the drive isn't encrypted. Otherwise  per john help from the IT dept would be required to get access.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot legally use an Education license when you are no longer
enrolled in the uni.

To save your files, use a Linux Live USB and boot it to copy your
files to an external disk or key.

To get a non-Education Windows 10, you could either:

- Revert back to your previous Windows version, before you
  upgraded to Windows 10, which may require an install
  (and perhaps a serial number).
  If lucky, you will then be eligible to upgrade to a Windows 10 version
  that is not Education.
- Otherwise, you will need to buy a retail version of Windows 10 in order
  to install it.

Comment: Worth pointing out either of those solutions require a clean install of Windows, there is no way to downgrade from Education to Professional